# Mysqli vs mysql, different result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have created a script local (Windows, xampp) and after checking everything if it works I moved it to a online server (Linux). Now I have a problem with collection results from my database. I have written everything using Mysqli, also with prepared statements and the first insert statement works perfect, but when I go to look at the results suddenly the program tells my he can't find the result.

I've got a table: session with columns: ID, CreatedOn and Name
When using the following lines of code i don't get any results

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID, Name FROM `session` WHERE Name = ?;"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

No results and no errors. The variable `$stmt->num_rows` have 0 as value. The variable $name contains: 'red'. when performing the query:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM `session` WHERE Name = 'red';
```

In phpmyadmin I get the results I want, when I test the code using the orginal mysql functions (mysql_connect, mysql_query and mysql_fetch_assoc). I get the results that I want.

Thus, the program is able to fetch the results that I want, only mysqli is not able to fetch them. I'm i doing something wrong? Or am i forgetting something?

Comment: it is not mysqli but your code. that does not fetch anything.

Comment: You are supposed to learn mysqli from a tutorial, instead of just putting together few random lines and then come asking what's wrong with them

Comment: Isn't it a little bit strange that there is a difference between the performance of code on a Windows and Linux machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ID, Name FROM `session` WHERE Name = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();  // add this line
    echo $stmt->num_rows;
}
```

Also you might want to check the documentation on `mysqli` first.

Comment: Thank this works, weird part is that I cant functions like 'use_result' on the Linux machine. Everything was working perfect I tested it rigorously. After I added the store result I needed to rewrite some part. I added: bind_result and $stmt->fetch(), and the collect the results perfectly.